# How to move from one view to another view using viewport in sencha?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, viewport

In my application I have a one view with topbar and some fields. In this button when I am click the login button I want to move to another view (Dashboard) which is a tabview. So for this I am using viewport. But I am unable to move from one view to another. Here is my code:

**app.js**

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled : true
});

Ext.application({
    views : ['TitlePanel', 'dashboardpanel'],
    models : [ 'MyModel', 'wishlistmodel' ],
    stores : [ 'name', 'wishlistsummarystore' ],
    name : 'MyApp',
    controllers : [ 'MyController' ],

    launch : function() {

        var Login = {
                xtype: 'login'
        }
        var Dashboard = {
                xtype: 'dashboard'
        }
        Ext.Viewport.add([Login, Dashboard]);
    }

});
```

**Titlepanel.js**

```
   Ext.define('MyApp.view.TitlePanel', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
alias: 'widget.login',
    config: {
        ui: 'light',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                id: 'LoginScreen',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'image',
                        docked: 'left',
                        height: 130,
                        id: 'Logoimage',
                        ui: '',
                        width: 170,
                        src: 'app/images/logo.png'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'titlebar',
                        cls: 'mytitlebar',
                        docked: 'top',
                        height: 100,
                        ui: 'blue',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'label',
                                height: 36,
                                html: 'Teritree Business Portal',
                                id: 'title',
                                margin: 20,
                                style: 'font: normal Bold 20px droid sans; color:#AB3951',
                                width: 396
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        id: 'LoginPanel',
                        layout: {
                            align: 'center',
                            type: 'vbox'
                        },
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'label',
                                html: 'Login with Teritree Business Credentials',
                                id: 'Loginlabel',
                                margin: 20,
                                style: 'font: normal Bold 30px droid sans',
                                ui: 'dark'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'fieldset',
                                height: 84,
                                itemId: 'LoginField',
                                margin: '40 0 0 0',
                                width: 500,
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                        id: 'user',
                                        style: 'font: Droid Sans',
                                        label: 'Login User id',
                                        labelWidth: '40%'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                        height: 35,
                                        id: 'password',
                                        label: 'Password',
                                        labelWidth: '40%'
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'button',
                                height: 40,
                                id: 'LoginBtn',
                                margin: 20,
                                ui: 'orange',
                                width: 180,
                                text: 'Login'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'label',
                                html: 'If you don\'t have an account yet: Signup at <a href="url">business.teritree.com</a> ',
                                id: 'signup',
                                margin: 20,
                                style: 'font: normal 24px droid sans'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
          ]
        }
    });
```

**dashboardpanel.js**

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.view.dashboardpanel', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
alias: 'widget.dashboard',
    id:'dashboardpanel',
    fullscreen: true,
    tabBarDock: 'bottom',
    items: [
            mainWindow   
           ]
});
    var mainWindow = new Ext.Panel({
    title:'main',
    iconCls:'home',
    layout:'fit',
    scroll: 'vertical',
    dockedItems: [toolbar,bigButton]
});

var bigButton = new Ext.Button({
    dock: 'bottom',
    text: 'I should be at the bottom'
});

var toolbar = new Ext.Toolbar({
    dock: 'top',
    title: 'Main',
    items: [
        {
            text: 'Reload',
        }
    ]
});
```

**MyContrller.js**

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyController', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config : {
        refs : {
            LoginScreen : '#Login',
            dashboardscreen : '#dashboardpanel'
        },

        control : {
            "#LoginBtn" : {
                tap : 'onLoginButtonTap'
            }
        }
    },

    slideLeftTransition: { type: 'slide', direction: 'left' },

    onLoginButtonTap : function(button, e, options) {
           Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(Dashboard, this.slideLeftTransition);
    }

});
```

Comment: btw : If you're using ST2 (which I don't know because you tagged the question with both ST and ST2) it is good practice to create you component (for instance a panel) with Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{...}); and not with new Ext.Panel({...});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey i am able to solve this problem finally. Because iwas giving wrong references in controller..here is the controller code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyController', {
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
config : {
    refs : {
        TitlePanel : 'login',
        dashboardpanel : 'dashboard'
    },

    views : [
             'TitlePanel',
             'dashboardpanel'
         ],

    control : {
        "#LoginBtn" : {
            tap : 'onLoginButtonTap'
        }
    }
},

slideLeftTransition: { type: 'slide', direction: 'left' },

onLoginButtonTap : function(button, e, options) {

    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(this.getDashboardpanel(), this.slideLeftTransition);
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(1);
```

PS: Please notice the viewport case.

Comment: I edited my question. now i am not getting any error. I added one viewport.js class. And trying to show the screens on that. But it is giving me white screen. Where i am wrong??

Answer (score 1):

Hey @Arindam just put into your MyController file like this,

```
Ext.define('myapp.controller.MyController', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config : {
       refs : {
           LoginScreen: '#Login',
           dashboardscreen : '#Dashboard'
       },

       control : {
            "#LoginBtn": {
                tap : 'onLoginButtonTap'
            }
       }
    },

    onLoginButtonTap: function(button, e, options) {
         Ext.getCmp('dashboardpanel').show('slide', true)
         Ext.getCmp('loginpanel').hide()
    }
});
```

And you have some bugs into dashboardpanel.js file.

**I hope this helps :)**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I changed the app.js..now it is coming. But in app.js, i have to write the names of the all views right??  And now how can i move to dashboard screen..using your code, is it possible.

Comment: Now I showed you where you have to make the change to the Controller. Please. Look at **MyController**. Only that your `dashboardpanel.js` file it's wrong. Please. Or, what do you want?. I don't understand you. Please.

Comment: it is throwing the below exception while pressing the login button:   TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Ext.getCmp('dashboardpanel').show') at file:///android_asset/www/app/controller/MyController.js:34

Comment: ooohh I see, try launch with `http://your_ip:your_port/your_project_name/your_app_name`. Please.

Comment: Please try this `Ext.getCmp(idPanelMain).setActiveItem(Ext.getCmp(idPanelShow), {type: 'slide', direction: 'right'})`. Please.

Comment: I changed my code. But i am getting reference error. i ma fade up

Comment: still getting the error:  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Dashboard at file:///android_asset/www/app/controller/MyController.js:40

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `Ext.navigation.View` for this.
You can just add viewport in app.js, then in viewport add navigation view, on that navigation view you can push you TitlePanel, and then form button click in the TitlePanel, just push your  dashboardpanel.

Comment: Can you just modify the code and give me..because i tried with navigation view, but not able to do.