# Moving to another view in sencha-touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

Instead of writing all the components in the view itself, ,i have given a link to a HTML file in my view like below. I called sample.html on panelActivate().

So in this case, i have a button in sample.html and  i want to write click event for that button for going from one view to another. So how will i do that? I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468254/how-to-move-from-one-view-to-another-view-using-viewport-in-sencha) method wont work

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'main',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.Video',
        'Ext.Ajax'
    ],
    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        id            : 'MyPanel',
        itemId        : 'MyPanel',
        scrollable    :  true,
        listeners: [
        {
            fn: 'onMyPanelActivate',
            event: 'activate'
        }
    ],    

        items: [
            {
                title: '<div class="small_logo"></div>',

                styleHtmlContent: true,
                scrollable: true,

                html: [


                ].join("")
            }

        ]
    },

      onMyPanelActivate: function(newActiveItem, container, oldActiveItem, eOpts) {
        Ext.Ajax.request({

        scriptTag:true,
        url: ' resources/html/sample.html',
        success : function(response) {
           Ext.getCmp('MyPanel').setHtml(response.responseText);

        },
        failure : function(response) {  
            var text = response.responseText;
            Ext.Msg.alert('Error', text, Ext.emptyFn);            }
    });
```

}
});

Comment: In my humble opinion you are pretty much raping the framework. If you are looking for component separation/reuse define your custom button using Ext.define(), give it an xtype and include it in your parent view with it. Also could you show us the contents of `sample.html` to help us understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: so its not possible in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, post the contents of `sample.html` to help us understand, what I can say for sure is that there is no reason to do a local Ajax to separate code in a Sencha Touch application.

Comment: my HTML file is simple consisting of some buttons and images. In the next page, i have some description regarding the button that was clicked and nothing else. So do i have to change the complete HTML to sencha components now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its wrong use of the framework but it can be done using jquery and writing the click events
on onMyPanelActivate success.